# iterm2 ssh is using escape chars instead of "esc", "left", "right" buttons

Tags: macos, ssh, iterm2

Silly question, but when I am ssh'ed inside iterm2, the arrow keys and esc become escape chars, e.g. right becomes "^[[C". In the [faq](https://iterm2.com/faq.html) it states:

> For the normal mode, iTerm2 generates ESC [ sequences. For the cursor application mode, iTerm2 generates ESC O sequences.

However I do not believe ssh is considered a cursor application mode. How do I fix this so that I can scroll through previous commands or move my cursor left or right in ssh mode?

Comment: In your settings, under *Profiles » Default » Keys*, what preset are you using? Or did you ever change anything there? On the remote server, what's the `TERM` variable set to (run `echo $TERM`)?

Comment: My preset is "xterm Defaults" and TERM variable is set to "term-256color".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the ubuntu stack exchange community: https://askubuntu.com/questions/325807/arrow-keys-tab-complete-not-working

> That probably means that the new user account was created with /bin/sh as its login shell (which symlinks to the dash shell by default) instead of /bin/bash - you can change a user's login shell with the 'chsh' command
>
> sudo chsh -s /bin/bash 
>   (you will need to log out and back in for the change to take effect). You may also need to copy the default .bashrc from /etc/skel to get the color prompt.
>
> In future you might want to use the 'adduser' command instead of 'useradd' - it sets up a more complete user environment including things like a default .profile and .bashrc - as well as setting the login shell to 'bash'

I believe I created my user with "useradd" instead of "adduser" and thus was using the wrong shell.